# MS .Net 2.0 Framework Oracle Data Provider OR Oracle 9i/10g/11g Data Provider?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, asp.net-2.0

For those that are knowledgeable in this subject (and hopefully faced a similar situation), could you please give your opinion on which provider would be best suited for a ASP.net 2.0 framework application?

The main points I am looking for are:

1. Performance
2. Functionality

From what I have gathered online, it seems the Oracle provided Data Providers provide better performance and functionality but you need to install and setup the clients/server software which can be a hassle.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question. The Oracle ODP provides more functionality (I am not sure about the performance though) while the Microsoft ODP provides simpler deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I found the ability to do bulk inserts using the odp.net driver really useful. It allows you to pass arrays of parameters to a stored procedure to do a bulk crud operations.

So I guess from a performance and functionality perspective this is worth it.

I'm not sure if the odp.net driver works with Enterprise Library, if you intend on using that also.